# Azure IoT Hub TLS Options

Tags: c, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use the Azure IoT C SDK on a Linux based system and am required to use certain TLS Options, e.g. no TLS compression. The API doesn't seem to mention a way to set TLS options, but in case I missed the reference, please prove me wrong.

I have found out that:

- The SDK sets certain options by default
- The SDK transfers options through the application/protocol stack
- The SDK can set certain TLS options, for example those pertaining to X509 certificates

I was not able to find any way to set options like the accepted ciphers or the aforementioned TLS compression. The TLS compression option can be enabled or disabled at compile time, though. I am also aware that those options would be specific to the underlying library which is used for securing connections, in my case openssl.

So I want to know:

- Is there a way to set TLS options that I'm missing?
- If not is there some way to set them, even if that way is not straightforward (e.g. not using the IotHubClient_SetOption methods)

Comment: What kind of your Linux system and which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: I am running Gentoo Linux. For testing purposes I used the X509 certificate sample contained in the C SDK.

Comment: I want to set TLS options however and as far as I'm aware neither the IoTHubClient_ (or _LL versions) nor the transport protocol options allow me to directly influence the TLS options.